# C++ Operator overloading - 'recreating the Vector'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am currently in a collage second level programing course... We are working on operator overloading... to do this we are to rebuild the vector class... 
I was building the class and found that most of it is based on the `[] operator`. When I was trying to implement the `+ operator` I run into a weird error that my professor has not seen before (apparently since the class switched IDE's from MinGW to VS express...) (I am using Visual Studio Express 2008 C++ edition...)

### Vector.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef _VECTOR_H
#define _VECTOR_H

const int DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE = 5;

class Vector
{
private:
    int *   data;
    int     size;
    int     comp;
public:
    inline  Vector      (int Comp = 5,int Size = 0) 
        : comp(Comp), size(Size)    { if (comp > 0) { data = new int [comp]; } 
                                      else { data = new int [DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE];
                                      comp = DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE; }
                                    }
    int      size_      ()          const       { return size; }
    int      comp_      ()          const       { return comp; }
    bool     push_back  (int);
    bool     push_front (int);
    void     expand     ();
    void     expand     (int);
    void     clear      ();
    const    string at  (int);
    int&         operator[ ](int);
    int&         operator[ ](int) const;
    Vector&  operator+  (Vector&);
    Vector&  operator-  (const Vector&);
    bool     operator== (const Vector&);
    bool     operator!= (const Vector&);

    ~Vector() { delete [] data; }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Vector&);

#endif
```

### Vector.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Vector.h"
using namespace std;

const string Vector::at(int i) {
    this[i];
}

void Vector::expand() {
    expand(size);
}

void Vector::expand(int n ) {
    int * newdata = new int [comp * 2];
    if (*data != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (comp); i++) {
            newdata[i] = data[i];
        }
        newdata -= comp;
        comp += n;
        data = newdata;
    delete newdata;
    }
    else if ( *data == NULL || comp == 0) {
        data = new int [DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE];
        comp = DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE;
        size = 0;
    }
}

bool Vector::push_back(int n) {
    if (comp = 0) { expand(); }
    for (int k = 0; k != 2; k++) {
        if ( size != comp ){
            data[size] = n;
            size++;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            expand();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Vector::clear() {
    delete [] data;
    comp = 0;
    size = 0;
}
int& Vector::operator[] (int place) { return (data[place]); }
int& Vector::operator[] (int place) const { return (data[place]); }

Vector& Vector::operator+ (Vector& n) {
    int temp_int = 0;

    if (size > n.size_() || size == n.size_()) { temp_int = size; }
    else if (size < n.size_()) { temp_int = n.size_();  }

    Vector newone(temp_int);
    int temp_2_int = 0;

    for ( int j = 0; j <= temp_int && 
                     j <= n.size_() && 
                     j <= size; 
                                        j++) {
        temp_2_int = n[j] + data[j];
        newone[j] = temp_2_int;
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return newone;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Vector& n) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= n.size_(); i++) {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        out << n[i] << " ";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
    return out;
}
```

### Errors:

```
out << n[i] << " "; error C2678:
```

binary '[' : no operator found which
takes a left-hand operand of type
'const Vector' (or there is no
acceptable conversion)

```
return newone;
```

error C2106: '=' : left
operand must be l-value

---

As stated above, I am a student going into Computer Science as my selected major I would appreciate tips, pointers, and better ways to do stuff :D

Comment: The lines you are showing are not the ones that are causing the error messages. Also, is this supposed to be a vector of strings or of integers?

Comment: `*data = *newdata;`, as @Neil points out in his answer, is wrong:  you almost certainly mean `data = newdata;`.

Comment: You got an awful lot of help here that's specific to this assignment beyond just diagnosing your error. Hopefully it's okay with your professor and school to do that sort of thing - if not, you might want to avoid that sort of general help request in the future.

Comment: @Jefromi: I posted this on his request - a good point for others reading this though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
int operator[ ](int);
```

is a non-const member function.  It means that it cannot be called on a `const Vector`.

Usually, the subscript operator is implemented such that it returns a reference (if you return a value, like you are doing, you can't use it as an lvalue, e.g. you can't do `newone[j] = temp_2_int;` like you have in your code):

```
int& operator[](int);
```

In order to be able to call it on a const object, you should also provide a const version of the member function:

```
const int& operator[](int) const;
```

Since you ask for "tips, pointers, and better ways to do stuff:"

- You cannot name your include guard `_VECTOR_H`.  Names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.  There are [a lot of rules about underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).
- You should *never* use `using namespace std` in a header.
- Your `operator+` should take a `const Vector&` since it is not going to modify its argument.
- Your `at` should return an `int` and should match the semantics of the C++ standard library containers (i.e., it should throw an exception if `i` is out of bounds.  You need to use `(*this)[i]` to call your overloaded `operator[]`.
- You need to learn what the `*` operator does.  In several places you've confused pointers and the objects to which they point.
- Watch out for confusing `=` with `==` (e.g.  in `if (comp = 0)`).  The compiler *will* warn you about this.  Don't ignore warnings.
- Your logic will be much simpler if you guarantee that `data` is never NULL.

Comment: What is the difference between putting the `const` before vs after the function declaration?

Comment: @Wallter:  A const qualifier next to the return type const qualifies the return type (i.e., in this example, you return a reference to a const int).  A const qualifier at the end of the function declaration const qualifies the member function (i.e., the `this` pointer in the member function is const qualified and you can't change any non-mutable members variables of the object or call any non-const member functions).

Comment: the `const` before makes the `int&` constant. the `const` after means that the method `operator[]()` doesn't change anything in the object that it acts on.

Comment: The way I like to think of it is that the final `const` makes `this` a const pointer.

Comment: I would replace the return type `const int&` with `int`.

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason to never using namespace std (or anything) in a header is that including that header in any source file causes symbols to be unexpectedly brought into the global namespace of the includer and can then cause various problems.

Answer (score 3):

Can't fit this into a comment on Neil's answer, so I'm gonna have to go into more detail here.

Regarding your `expand()` function.  It looks like this function's job is to expand the internal storage, which has `comp` elements, by `n` elements, while maintaining the `size` of the Vector.  So let's walk through what you have.

```
void Vector::expand(int n) {
    int * newdata = new int [comp * 2];
```

Okay, you just created a new array that is twice as big as the old one.  Error: Why doesn't the new size have anything to do with `n`?

```
    if (*data != NULL) {
```

Error: `*data` is the first `int` element in your array.  It's not a pointer.  Why is it being compared to `NULL`?

Concept Error: Even if you said `if (data != NULL)`, which could be a test to see if there is an array at all, at what point in time is `data` ever set to `NULL`?  `new []` doesn't return `NULL` if it's out of memory; it throws an exception.

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= (comp); i++) {
            newdata[i] = data[i];
        }
```

Warning: You're copying the whole array, but only the first `size` elements are valid.  The loop could just run up to `size` and you'd be fine.

```
        newdata -= comp;
```

Error: Bad pointer math.  `newdata` is set to a pointer to who knows where (`comp` `int`s back from the start of `newdata`?!), and almost certainly a pointer that will corrupt memory if given to `delete []`.

```
        comp += n;
```

This is fine, for what it is.

```
        data = newdata;
        delete newdata;
    }
```

Error: You stored a pointer and then immediately deleted its memory, making it an invalid pointer.

```
    else if ( *data == NULL || comp == 0) {
        data = new int [DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE];
        comp = DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE;
        size = 0;
    }
}
```

Error: This should be in your constructor, not here.  Again, nothing ever sets `data` to `NULL`, and `*data` is an `int`, not a pointer.

What this function *should* do:

- create a new array of `comp + n` elements
- copy `size` elements from the old array to the new one
- delete the old array
- set `data` to point to the new array

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Besides of what others already wrote about your `operator[]()`:

Your `operator+()` takes the right-hand side per non-`const` reference - as if it would attempt to change it. However, with `A+B` everyone would expect `B` to remain unchanged.

Further, I would implement all binary operators treating their operands equally (i.e., not changing either of them) as non-member functions. As member functions the left-hand side (`this`) could be treated differently. (For example, it could be subjected to overwritten versions in derived classes.)

Then, IME it's always good to base `operator+()` on `operator+=()`. `operator+=()` does not treat its operands equally (it changes its left one), so it's best done as a member function. Once this is done, implementing `operator+()` on top of it is a piece of cake.

Finally, `operator+()` should never, never ever return a reference to an object. When you say `A+B` you expect this to return a new object, not to change some existing object and return a reference to that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide two versions of your operator[]. For accessing:

```
T operator[](std::size_t idx)const;
```

For writing to the element:

```
T& operator[](std::size_t idx);
```

In both of the above, replace T with the type of the elements. The reason you have this problem is that only functions that are marked "const" may be invoked on an object declared to be "const". Marking all non-mutating functions as "const" is definitely something you should do and is called "const-correctness". Since returning a reference to an element (necessary for writing) allows the underlying object to be mutated, that version of the function cannot be made "const". Therefore, a read-only "const" overload is needed.

You may also be interested in reading:

- [Const Correctness from the C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)
- [Const Correctness in C++](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html)

Comment: The first one really needs to be `const T operator[](size_t idx) const`. Otherwise a type T with reference members can still be modified.

Comment: @sblom, I am assuming that T will not alias the object in a modifiable manner, which I think is a reasonable assumption, but your criticism is nevertheless a valid one.

Comment: @sblom: In fact, since you don't know what `T` users might push onto your code, it might be best to return `const T&` from the `const` version of `operator[]()`. So long as it's only built-ins, returning a copy is fine (and I don't see much benefit in making this `const`), but for user-defined types (say, a vector fo strings) that could be expensive.

Comment: There is no difference whatsoever between `int function()` and `const int function()`, because for scalar types like `int`, there is no such thing as a constant rvalue. See §3.10 section 9

Answer (score 1):

There are so many errors in your code that it is hard to know where to start. Here's one:

```
 delete [] data;
 *data = *newdata;
```

You delete a pointer and then immediately dereference it.

And:

```
const string Vector::at(int i) {
    this[i];
}
```

This is (I think) a vector of ints. why is this returning a string? And applying the [] operator to this does not call your operator[] overload - it treats this as an array, which it isn't.

Comment: We are required to write the class in response to the teacher's `driver.cpp`
I was under the impression that once i called the `delete [] data;` it would delete the data pointed to by `*data` - Is there a better way to expand the array (to gain the functionality of the traditional <vector> class?)

Comment: @Walter Once you delete a pointer, you cannot dereference it. This is a logic error in your code, nothing to do with your teacher's driver program.

Comment: Might want to point out that the right way to write `at()` would be `return (*this)[i];`.

Comment: @Mike No, it isn't, because as I pointed out this is an array of ints!

Comment: @Walter: To expand an array *without discarding what is there*, you need to create a new array, copy elements over from the old array, initialize the values in the expanded area (unless you just want to use their default constructor), then delete the old array and set `data` to point to the new array.  In that order.

Comment: so to do it correctly: i would have to delete each member of the array, then reference it to `newdata`?

Comment: @Neil: Da, missed the return type.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Vector::operator[] (int place) { return (data[place]); }
```

This should be

```
int Vector::operator[] (int place) const { return (data[place]); }
```

so that you will be able to do the `[]` operation on const vectors. The `const` after the function declaration means that the class instance (`this`) is treated as `const Vector`, meaning you won't be able to modify normal attributes. Or in other words: A method that only has read access to attributes.

Comment: from the comments below... once this is added the errors go away... but do i need a function declaration with out the `const` in it?

Comment: @Wallter: Sure, the function I described in my answer is only for read access when using a `const Vector` instance. If you want to assign values in the vector, like `v[0] = 5;`, you'll have to implement a non-const equivalent which returns a reference which can be assigned to.